# Yii Framework File Upload

Tags: php, image, file-upload, yii

I'm trying to learn how to upload an image file in Yii. I'm using this code

```
    <?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>

    <button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

in ProjectFile/views/site/upload.php file.
The problem is in

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
```

$model gives me a red underline. I have looked many examples and all of them wrote the like this.
What I need to do stop this problem?

***Edit:***
Is inside the controller/SiteController.php

```
// function for upload
    public function actionUploadImage()
    {
        $model = new UploadImageForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

Is inside of models/UploadImageForm.php

```
<?php


namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadImageForm extends \yii\base\Model
{

    public $imageFile;

    // gives rules of how to upload picture
    public function rules(){
        return [
          [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }

    // uploads picture
    public function upload(){
        if($this->validate()){
            $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you followed the guide as in the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload)?

Comment: Red underline - you mean file input field gets red border and some error message appears under/above/near the field? If that is your case, then you have validations issues. Provide please code of rules method of your model(which is used in form)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal Yes, I looked to the documentation you shared.

Comment: @neolodor which type validation I need to use?

Comment: @gun depends on file storage logic you want to implement: if you want just to upload file in some directory on server then follow [yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload)

As I see from update you've done ok. but:
1. Model method `upload` must return some result. In your case it returns nothing.
2. After invalid attempt to upload file look to error log - may be you have some file permissions issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views\upload.php the red underline is shown because the system can't find the $model. While running, program will connect $model to controller. So the red underline is not a problem for php files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please make sure that model has attribute/field called "imageFile"
2. Check your editor do you get red line on your editor then its your editor related issue

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, your view code is pretty fine. Mine was also the same, I made it work by using these lines in model function:

```
$imageFile= UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFile')[0];
$imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $imageFile->baseName . '.' . $imageFile->extension);
```

and in controller action:

```
$model->imageFile= UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFile')[0];
```